# Is there any need for LINQ to SQL Entity classes to implement INotifyPropertyChanging in an ASP.NET MVC Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am using the code generated using SQLMetal for my database entities. They all implement INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged, and because of those dependencies, their is a ton of extra code in the property setters. I couldn't think of an instances for a regular ol' web page where one object would need to be notified of another's property change. If it a property is going to change, shouldn't you be able to handle it with the accompanying HTTP request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces are used primarily for user interface data binding, like the data binding which occurs in ASP.NET, Winforms and WPF.  You are correct that this would be of limited or no use in an MVC application, where "data binding" takes place using a different mechanism.

Linq to SQL was designed to be a "general purpose" tool, to include its use in other application types besides ASP.NET MVC...application types that would make better use of data binding.